# Airflow Dynamic Task Mapping identifiers in UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

With the new [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) feature, it's possible to use the `expand` function and create a variable number of tasks based on the output of a previous task.

The problem is that, as shown in the documentation, the UI will only show the total number of tasks generated, this is particularly uncomfortable when the number of task instances is high and we need to debug a specific error.

I tried searching the docs and GitHub pages but all I could find is [a suggestion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/25105). Is there anyone who found a solution or a workaround to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem.
I found this thread: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/22073
And this one: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28183

Summary: it looks like it's not possible right now.